# Module doesn't appear on update.php

Tags: hooks, updating

I wanted to add columns to my module schema, I added an update hook `hook_update_6031`
however when I go to the update.php script my module isn't listed at all, not even as "no updates". Do I have to provide some hook to have my module be listed? I can't seem to find any documentation on how to write updates other than the function documentation for `hook_update` or looking at some other module code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Is your update function placed in [modulename].module or in [modulename].install? It should be in the install file.
- Is the function really called hook_update_6031? in that case, replace 'hook' with the name of your module. For instance, an update function for the comment module could be called [comment_update_6003](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.install/function/comment_update_6003/6).

If the above does not help, please update your question with the code of your update function. Also check the value in the `schema_version` column in the `system` table for your module - for the [modulename]_update_6031 function, it must not be less than 6031, but not -1.

Comment: haha, apparently I did name it hook_update, I changed it and it works fine.

Comment: Glad I could help. I think every Drupal developer makes that mistake at least once :-)

Comment: Also important, ***always*** make your module name lower case only.   Update functions aren't detected for modules with upper case characters in them, although other hooks are.

Comment: @Berdir that's interesting, I didn't know that. Is there a good reason for this behavior?

Comment: Yes. Calling functions is case insensitive, so hooks work. But update functions are detected by manually looking at defined functions: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--install.inc/function/drupal_get_schema_versions/6

Comment: Actually, the D7 version of that function has been changed, so it *might* work in D7, I am not sure. Shouldn't be done anyway, though :)

Comment: Fortunately, using uppercase chars in module names has never even crossed my mind, so I'm safe :-)